# Added a for loop to my code, and it seemed to have run faster, how is this possible?

Tags: c++

I added a for loop to specifically slow down my code for an assignment so that I would not appear as high on the leaderboards so that later I could take the top spot on this assignment.  In any case, I decided to try to add a for loop to waste time. Here is what I added to the beginning:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 123456; i++){ std::cout << "" << "" << "";}
```

Effectively that is what I added.  Once the time got back to me it was lower.

My guess is that either the compiler optimized out the whole section, and due to the other processes the computer that graded the assignment was running at the time it was a little less busy and ran faster, or somehow the compiler was able to use some part of this to optimize the code a little bit. I'm just curious if the answer is one of these 2, or something more obscure that might surprise me.

I was using the g++ compiler with the -O2 argument if it makes a difference.

thanks.

Comment: On a side note, Why don't you use `std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(X))` to "waste" time?

Comment: This is impossible to answer without the surrounding code.

Comment: You can validate your guess by looking at the generated assembly

Comment: to delay the code add this `i = 100000000; while (i--);` Roughly 10^8 operations is 1 second delay.

Comment: @PRP: compiler is allowed to transform your whole loop by `i = -1;`

Answer (score 2):

Your compiler probably optimized this section out:

```
std::cout << "" << "" << "";
```

Leaving you with an empty for-loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 123456; i++){}
```

Which can also be optimized out, because the value of the variable *i* can be safely ignored.

The way I solve this (to create simple SW delays) is to make the index variable for the for-loop *volatile*. This way the compiler is force to read and write *i* (volatile tells it that *i* may change unexpectedly, and has therefore to be updated each time it is accessed).

```
for (volatile int i = 0; i <= 123456; i++){}
```

You can now even leave your loop empty as it is not needed. Your delay loop will simply read, increment and store *i* repeatedly.

Here is my simple SW delay loop (I wrote it from memory, it might need some tweaking):

```
void delay(unsigned long long c)
{
    for(volatile unsigned long long i = 0; i<c; i++);
}
```

Now you can simply call delay, and try out several values to see how much your code slows down. Nevertheless, be warned that this delay puts your CPU at 100% load. Better use a library as others have suggested in the comments.

```
delay(123456); // CPU hungry beast. Not recommended
```